# How can I get the path of an image in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter, form-data

In my app I take a photo and then save it in the device, but then I don’t know how to get the path of that image, because the directory is root. This my code:

This is where I take the photo:

```
Future<String> takePicture() async {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
        showInSnackBar('Error: select a camera first.');
        return null;
    }
    final Directory extDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final String dirPath = '${extDir.path}/Pictures/flutter_test';
    await new Directory(dirPath).create(recursive: true);
    final String filePath = '$dirPath/${timestamp()}.jpg';

    if (controller.value.isTakingPicture) {
        // A capture is already pending, do nothing.
        return null;
    }

    try {
        await controller.takePicture(filePath);
    }
    on CameraException catch (e) {
        _showCameraException(e);
        return null;
    }
    return filePath;
}
```

This is the trigger:

```
void onTakePictureButtonPressed() {
    takePicture().then((String filePath) {
        if (mounted) {
            setState(() {
                imagePath = filePath;
                videoController?.dispose();
                videoController = null;
            });

            upload(File(filePath));

            print(filePath);
            if (filePath != null)
                showInSnackBar('Picture saved to $filePath');
        }
    });
}
```

And this is where I want to send the image in formdata:

```
upload(File imageFile) async {

    // Open a bytestream
    var stream = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(imageFile.openRead()));

    // Get file length
    var length = await imageFile.length();

    // String to URI
    var uri = Uri.parse("http://ip/something/else/here");

    // Create a multipart request
    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

    // Multipart that takes file
    var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('file', stream, length,
        filename: basename(imageFile.path));

    // Add file to multipart
    request.files.add(multipartFile);

    // Send
    var response = await request.send();
    print(response.statusCode);

    // Listen for a response
    response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
        print(value);
    });
}
```

when I take a photo, that returns:

> {"error":"http: no such file"}

It's as if the API did not receive anything. I think it is because the location is only root.

How can I modify that to get access to the image?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out which part is having an error. I can't run your code atm, could you provide [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that I would be able to trace what's going on with your implementation. Also, I've noticed that you are trying to capture an image and save it to your device. AFAIK, there is an existing plugin that could do this functionality, [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker).

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code you've provided retaining only the parts to generate a file path and it works without issues. With `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()`, I assume that you're using `path_provider` package.

```dart
Future<String> takePicture() async {
  // if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
  //   showInSnackBar('Error: select a camera first.');
  //   return null;
  // }
  final Directory extDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  final String dirPath = '${extDir.path}/Pictures/flutter_test';
  await new Directory(dirPath).create(recursive: true);
  final String filePath = '$dirPath/${timestamp()}.jpg';

  // if (controller.value.isTakingPicture) {
  //   // A capture is already pending, do nothing.
  //   return null;
  // }

  // try {
  //   await controller.takePicture(filePath);
  // } on CameraException catch (e) {
  //   _showCameraException(e);
  //   return null;
  // }
  return filePath;
}

String timestamp() {
  // DateFormat uses intl package
  // https://pub.dev/packages/intl
  return DateFormat('y-MM-dd-HHms').format(DateTime.now());
}
```

I suggest verifying if the image has been created to troubleshoot the issue. The error from the logs provided seems to originate from your `upload()` task.

Also, `DelegatingStream.typed()` has been deprecated. Please `http.ByteStream(StreamView<List<int>>).cast()` instead.

```dart
Stream<List<int>> stream = http.ByteStream(imageFile.openRead()).cast();
```